# How can I find where a class is created in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Say I'm in a header file where a class is defined, and I want to know where this class is created/newed.
I know "Reference" gives you all places where class name appear. But what I want is more accurate: where this class is instantiated. Is Eclipse LUNA CDT smart enough to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You go to your class header file and there you select a specific *constructor* of your class. Then you ask Eclipse to "Open Call Hierarchy" (usually through right-click menu). It will show you all the places where this specific constructor is called.

Comment: hmmmmm, this seems more like a work-around by using Open Call Hierarchy for a method. If I want to list all places where it's created in a single shot this won't work, but anyway it works somehow. :)